# new features for autocomplete algorithm

Tags: algorithm, autocomplete, search-engine

I met this problem in an interview. It is easy to implement a basic autocomplete system(https://www.futurice.com/blog/data-structures-for-fast-autocomplete/) to get a list of string from the prefix string. Now we want to add some new features.

ex,
User input: lun pla Output: lunch plan (mutiple words autocomplete)

User input: pla Output: lunch plan

User input: unc Output: lunch (autocomplete form part of the word)

How to implement the features?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I used "Alphabetical vocabulary" in the link. I store all the string in a list and sort it. Then I use binary search to find the first and last string started with the given prefix. This method can only deal with prefix autocomplete. I have no idea how to add these new features.

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to illustrate the specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following (basic) approach, and I will later give suggestions for extensions:

- load a dictionary of accepted words
- build a [BK-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BK-tree) out of these words using [Levenshtein-Damerau distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance) as the underlying metric
- split an input sequence on the whitespace character to get words
- for each word, check whether it is an accepted word. If it isn't find the nearest (within acceptable distance) word in the BK-tree

Now for the improvements:

- As you indicated, sometimes a match makes more sense when two words are grouped together
- Use the Google word2Phrase algorithm for this. You can find a C++ version [here](https://github.com/chrisjmccormick/word2vec_commented/blob/master/word2phrase.c).
- Use a more clever approach to finding word-boundaries. A stochastic method like HMM (Hidden Markov Model) might be useful (to avoid dates, times, abbreviations, etc being split)
- Use a more intelligent error-metric. You could take into account common misspellings, keyboard layout errors (there are very specific errors for people that are used to typing qwerty that are suddenly faced with azerty), etc
- Try to determine word [part-of-speech type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging). (Adjective, noun, verb, etc). By doing this you can make much better completions.